# default value in advance search while transition from SSearch to Advance Search Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

When user Enters some value in search box and clickes advance search , that value which was there in the searchBox should appear as a default value for same key.

For e.g. value "as" is present by default which is a value for "Has the Word".

Simple Search----
[image: Simple Search]

Advance Search-----

[image: Advance Search]

How to achieve this using Jquery?

Comment: ask to make your job is not the right approach. Tell us what you tried/sought and we will help you if you encounter problems.

Comment: I am not asking for any code. Just the approch. In advance Search dialog,how i can access the value in the Search box. using $el or $input??

Answer (score 0):

When user click on advance search, at that click fetch value me search input box using jquery using function and put that value in "has the word" input box

```
var DATA=$(#searchboxid).val()

$(#hasthewordsid).val(DATA)
```